# Looking for a 1000 most frequent english words

Tags: phrase-request, word-usage, dictionaries

Is there a free list of 1000 most frequent words used in everyday English? If there is a list with usage examples (as each of those words has multiple meanings for sure, not to cound phrasal verbs), it would be even greater.

Is there something alike, but with phrases? (E.g. 1000 most frequent phrases)

Comment: Google seems to return quite a few examples:
https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Most_frequent_1000_words_in_English

Comment: http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp?s=y

Comment: @snailboat That's exactly what I was looking for. Convert it to an answer, please!

Comment: @snailboat-That's an astonishing list. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the list:

http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp?s=y

it  includes all of the 1000 words, except with 4000 more.

You can ignore the extra 4000 if you want.

Hope this helps!!